# Errors when opening PhpMyAdmin 5.2.0 on wampserver 3.3.0 using localhost (Windows 10 64-bit)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am a first time user of wamp/php etc and have followed the installation steps as instructed. All three services (Apache, MariaDB, MySQL) are running properly. I can open Adminer 4.8.1 and PhpSysInfo 3.4.2 without any issue. My PHP version is 8.2.0. Apache server is 2.4.54.2

I just can't open phpMyAdmin window. Instead, I see the below list of error messages when I try to do so.

[image]

I am not sure what to make out of these error messages and how to go about reolving them. All help is appreciated. Thanks

I have tried downloading and using other versions of phpMyAdmin but they have been flagged incompatable with the version of PHP I am using hence I couldn't get to the stage where I could reproduce the same error with these other versions.

**This is the error in text:**

```
( ! ) Notice: include(): Read of 5359 bytes failed with errno=9 Bad file descriptor in D:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin5.2.0\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 571
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0185  364224  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.2788  447456  PhpMyAdmin\Common::run( )   ...\index.php:40
3   0.2865  450056  PhpMyAdmin\Http\Factory\ServerRequestFactory::createFromGlobals( )  ...\Common.php:84
4   0.2920  450848  Slim\Psr7\Factory\ServerRequestFactory::createFromGlobals( )    ...\ServerRequestFactory.php:41
5   0.3139  531160  Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass( $class = 'Slim\\Psr7\\Cookies' )  ...\ServerRequestFactory.php:99
6   0.3139  531160  Composer\Autoload\includeFile( $file = 'D:\\wamp64\\apps\\phpmyadmin5.2.0\\vendor\\composer/../slim/psr7/src/Cookies.php' ) ...\ClassLoader.php:428

( ! ) Warning: include(): Failed opening 'D:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin5.2.0\vendor\composer/../slim/psr7/src/Cookies.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin5.2.0\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 571
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0185  364224  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.2788  447456  PhpMyAdmin\Common::run( )   ...\index.php:40
3   0.2865  450056  PhpMyAdmin\Http\Factory\ServerRequestFactory::createFromGlobals( )  ...\Common.php:84
4   0.2920  450848  Slim\Psr7\Factory\ServerRequestFactory::createFromGlobals( )    ...\ServerRequestFactory.php:41
5   0.3139  531160  Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass( $class = 'Slim\\Psr7\\Cookies' )  ...\ServerRequestFactory.php:99
6   0.3139  531160  Composer\Autoload\includeFile( $file = 'D:\\wamp64\\apps\\phpmyadmin5.2.0\\vendor\\composer/../slim/psr7/src/Cookies.php' ) ...\ClassLoader.php:428

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Slim\Psr7\Cookies" not found in D:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin5.2.0\vendor\slim\psr7\src\Factory\ServerRequestFactory.php on line 99
( ! ) Error: Class "Slim\Psr7\Cookies" not found in D:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin5.2.0\vendor\slim\psr7\src\Factory\ServerRequestFactory.php on line 99
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0185  364224  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.2788  447456  PhpMyAdmin\Common::run( )   ...\index.php:40
3   0.2865  450056  PhpMyAdmin\Http\Factory\ServerRequestFactory::createFromGlobals( )  ...\Common.php:84
4   0.2920  450848  Slim\Psr7\Factory\ServerRequestFactory::createFromGlobals( )    ...\ServerRequestFactory.php:41
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What do you have inside your `C:\php`?